# AVFoundation Value of option type 'String?' not unwrapped, App Crashes, won't play sound

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to play a simple sound when I push a button. xcode is forcing me to use a "!" for my NSURL for the audio file, I followed other tutorials for how to play a sound in swift and for some reason I keep getting this error, why!? Code:

```
import UIKit
```

import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("buttonSound", ofType: "mp3")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)

    player.prepareToPlay()


}

@IBAction func button21(sender: AnyObject) {

    player.play()



}
```

}

When I do add the "!", the app will load without crashing, when I press the button the app crashes and the log outputs "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: The error means that your path is nil.

Comment: @rdelmar care to specify, or show me how to fix it? I dont understand what that means, how is my path nil? how can I change my path so it is the fileURL and play the sound without getting a error or crashing?

Comment: you have to unwrap the url

Comment: actually you have to unwrap two optionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    var yourSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("alarm2", ofType: "mp3")!)
    func prepareYourSound() {
        myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: yourSound, error: nil)
        myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareYourSound()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func playMySound(sender: AnyObject) {
        myPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

[image]

HERE is the project sample link

[Sample Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87285547/swift/OSX/testing.zip)

Comment: This did not do anything either, it still crashed with the same result, why is this even happening? did any 1 try to recreate this and see what happened for them? in all the other "how to play a sound with sprite kit tutorials, there is nothing like this and they all work, but not for me. did they change something in a reent xcode update? what is going on here

Comment: have you copied the file to your project?

Comment: you have to drag the sound to your project first

Comment: yes the sound file is in xcode this is so annoying... I dont even know what to tell you or how to guide you to fix it...

Comment: did you declare player var somewhere else?

Comment: i have var player = AVAudioPlayer() declared above class ViewController: UIViewController {

Comment: using if let it can't crash

Comment: did it crash using if let or nothing happened?

Comment: im still getting the same error, except now it crashes right away, not when i press the button

Comment: you should manually check if the file is where it is supposed to be

Comment: It should be in the same folder as the AppDelegate.swift

Comment: yes the file is in the correct spot, my code is the exact same as the code you provided above and I am still getting the error found nil while unwrapping optional after myPlayer.prepareToPlay() and the 3 closing brackets I have: @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        myPlayer.play()
    }
} soon as i push the button, i get the error.... in your version does the sound play when you push the button on your storyboard?

Comment: I tested here and it compiles clean and plays OK

Comment: this is just a sample for you to see how you have to position the elements

Comment: yes I was aware of that, I changed the file names so they matched up before I ran it... I still got the error.

Comment: I have tested the same code with another mp3 file and it worked without a problem the code is right

Comment: Thank you that worked! there is no difference between our projects but yours worked and mine didn't, strange... thanks a ton though!

Comment: actually if you're still here, i created a new project copied/pasted your code to mine, changed the sound name, and i run the code... I get the same error! this is very aggravating. it seems that when I try to use my sound I get this error but when I use your sound I dont, why is that?

Comment: have you played your sound inside xcode project window?

Comment: yes it works fine, could it be because of the length of my audio clip and the .mp3 extension? I noticed your clips where well over 15 seconds, while my clip is less than 1 second long... about .81 seconds I believe...

Comment: Try creating a sound with silent at the end

Comment: But I don't think thats your problem

Comment: send me your project I will try to fix

Comment: I can't play your sound

Comment: hmm hold on, i wonder if its because I changed the original file from .mp4 to .mp3, its playing on my mac so...

Comment: try exporting it again and make sure you are saving the right format file when choosing save as

Comment: I think the problem is the format you changed not the lenght

Comment: I changed the termination back to mp3, then I converted your sound to aif, dragged to your project and voila.

Answer (score 1):

Good to see your problem got solved. Just adding to the conversation:

I had the same issue as you and I followed the advice given by other people here, but it didn't get rid of my problem (`unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`). I'm using Xcode 6.1 and the thing that solved it for me was deleting the file and adding it again except this time, instead of dragging the file in, I did it by right-clicking the project folder and selecting the "Add Files to your_app's_name" option.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old now, but I had the same problem recently.

The way I fixed it was to select my file (an mp3, too) and go into the File Inspector and make sure the Target Membership was checked for my project.